# regarding a Java assignment and instance constants

Tags: java

I do not want the code answer to this, I want to figure this out myself. I have a question on the wording of this assignment and would like to clarify it please. The assignment asks for a instance constant to be created called ACCOUNT_NUMBER which will be created in the class SavingsAccount constructor. My question regarding this is that if the SavingsAccountDriver class is suppose to be used to input the data regarding the accounts (account number 10002 and 10003) , how do I change a variable that has been set to final already and requires a different number? Or am I looking at this wrong?

> Write a program that establishes two savings accounts with saver1 having account number 10002 with an initial balance of $2,000, and saver2 having account 10003 with an initial balance of $3,000. Set a common rate of interest at 5% per year. At the end of each month, update the balance by adding one month’s interest to the balance, so that the balance compounds monthly. Print an output that displays the month number and the account number and the balance for each of the two accounts. Use month 0 to display the initial balances, month 1 to display the balances after the first month’s interest, and so on. At the end of the year, display the total balance for both accounts combined, like this:
>
> Output:
>
> Monthly balances for one year with 0.05 annual interest:
>
> ```
> Month Account #   Balance Account #   Balance
> ----- ---------   ------- ---------   -------
>     0     10002   2000.00     10003   3000.00
>     1     10002   2008.33     10003   3012.50
>     2     10002   2016.70     10003   3025.05
>     3     10002   2025.10     10003   3037.66
>     4     10002   2033.54     10003   3050.31
>     5     10002   2042.02     10003   3063.02
>     6     10002   2050.52     10003   3075.79
>     7     10002   2059.07     10003   3088.60
>     8     10002   2067.65     10003   3101.47
>     9     10002   2076.26     10003   3114.39
>    10     10002   2084.91     10003   3127.37
>    11     10002   2093.60     10003   3140.40
>    12     10002   2102.32     10003   3153.49
>
> Final balance of both accounts combined: 5255.81
> ```
>
> Use two classes, a SavingsAccount class and a SavingsAccountDriver class.
>
> In the SavingsAccount class, declare a class variable called annualInterestRate, an **instance constant** called ACCOUNT_NUMBER, and an instance variable called balance. Provide a two-parameter constructor to initialize the instance constant and instance variable, and provide accessors for the instance constant and instance variable. Provide an addMonthlyInterest method to update the balance, by adding (balance * annualInterestRate / 12) to the current balance. Also provide a class method that sets the annual interest rate.
>
> In the SavingsAccountDriver class, instantiate the saver1 and saver2 objects. Set the annual interest rate at 0.05. Print the table heading lines. Use a for loop to print the initial account numbers and balances and the account numbers and balances each month after that month’s interest has been added. After the last month’s printout, compute and display the total of both balances.
>
> Make sure that you add appropriate program documentation, which includes
>
> - Project name
> - Programmers’ name in your group
> - Date
> - Description

Comment: You should [edit] your title. Currently it is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The member field is declared `final`, but is not initialized until the constructor is called. The `final` keyword means it cannot change after it had been set and in the case of an instance field it can only be set via static initialization or via the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's an instance field that must be `final` and that may be set in a constructor. As an example,

```
class Example {
  final String str;
  public Example(String str) {
    this.str = str; // <-- allowed. the constructor assigns a value. 
  }
}
```